# Zend Framework: How to call a controller action helper from a view script?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view

I have a custom controller action helper that I would like to be able to call from a view script. How can I achieve this?

### Solution:

**Warning:** You probably don't really want to call an action helper from your view script unless you aren't using any dispatch hooks. But if you really, *really* want to call your action helper:

```
$helper = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Myhelper');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afaik, you can't, and you should **not** that's MVC. Trying to solve such problem should be a potential warning on your design.

However, in some case you may need to achieve a similar thing.

For example, the flashMessenger() action helper aims to provide a simple way to share messages between requests, however it is not available in the view, you need to manually pass it to the view. I've myself written a wrapper to be able to use as a view helper.

So maybe try to be more explicit on what you're trying to achieve, and we may help you to know if there isn't a good alternative.

Comment: Good answer. I just realized what I was trying to do wasn't going to work anyway. I was trying to call some action helper functions in my layout, but `postDispatch()` had already been called, so it wasn't going to do anything after my `postDispatch()` code had executed. Back to the drawing board...

Comment: Any chance of adding that FlashMessenger view-helper to your excellent [bgylibrary](https://github.com/borisguery/bgylibrary) on github? ;-)

Comment: Hi David, thank you :), I just pushed that [view helper](https://github.com/borisguery/bgylibrary/blob/master/library/Bgy/View/Helper/FlashMessenger.php) on github. The usage is not yet documented but it's pretty straighforward, it is just a wrapper to the flashmessenger action helper.